# Jquery reading xml issue

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml file in local system.I can read the file with jquery  running it on IE and Firefox But I can not read the file using Chrome and Opera.Where is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
<title>AJAX </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //crossDomain: true,
        //contentType: "application/xml",
        contentType: "application/xml;charset=UTF-8",
        url: "YYYYAAGGu.xml",
        //url: "today10.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Currency').each(function(){
                var name = $(this).find("Isim").text()
                alert(name);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("An error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: just An error occured: error Error:

Comment: That would be the alert from the error handler. The request obviously fails so there should be something in the console (F12 tools/ firebug/ etc)- a type mismatch, possibly cross-domain failure too depending where this page is. If not check if the request response is as expected in the Network watch tab.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you are missing the semicolon ';'

`var name = $(this).find("Isam").text();`

Chrome/Opera sets the origin to null as you are calling the file locally. So try to use something like `http://localhost/YYYYAAGGu.xml` rather than call it form the file directory locally.

This is my code and it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/site.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Currency').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('Isam').text();
                alert(title);
            });
        },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
             alert('Error Loading File');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: semicolon exists in original file.And I try to run the file using http://localhost/YYYYAAGGu.xml but there is no changes.Still not working

Comment: Is this through apache and post your XML Document as well

Comment: thanks.Problem was solved.I  ran the file on server.The thing that is important is work of  html file on server.I can run the file giving a xml path adress and also giving xml url.